# Azure DevOps Release Pipelines with "Failed to fetch Kudu App Settings. Error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT x.x.x.x:443"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, kudu

When I'm running Azure DevOps pipeline with the Azure WebApp it is getting into failed stated with as below message.

> 2022-11-18T12:01:00.4889154Z ##[error]Error: Failed to fetch Kudu App Settings. Error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT x.x.x.x:443

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment agent isn't connecting to your app service. One way this can occur is if there's a transient network issue with your app service. These are uncommon, rare errors. As a workaround though, you can try creating a new app service and verify your deployment credentials.

A more common error is if you're deploying to an app service environment (ASE). This type of app service doesn't allow traffic from the internet. To correct this error, you'll need to configure a deployment agent that is on the same VNET as your app service